# sum method alternatives for active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in a legacy Ruby on Rails project. Rails v2.3.9.

I have a model class `product`, in database there is `products` table.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...
end
```

There is `price` attribute which is a integer type.

I got all products (ActiveRecords) at some point.  I need to calculate the total price of all products I got. I know I can do:

```
total_price = all_products.sum(&:price)
```

It works.

But it also triggers a database query `SELECT sum(...)`. Is there an alternative way to calculate the summation of price of all products without triggering any database query?  I know I can use for loop, but I wonder any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

`sum` with block is delegated to Enumerable and it will always hit the database if `all_products` is not previously loaded, so you have to make sure it is not being lazy loaded.

In terms of performance, SUM query would be the fastest way to get the result as it doesn't need to load all records and makes the operation in the database and not in memory.

In your case, if you have the collection loaded and still creating a query, you can use

```
total_price = all_products.map(&:price).sum
```

which will default to kindof rockusbacchus solution

```
.inject { |sum, element| sum + element }
```

Comment: You can check the code  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L57

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the products loaded into all_products, you can use Ruby's inject method to sum the prices like so:

```
total_price = all_products.inject(0){|accumulator, product| accumulator + product.price}
```

However, you will likely find that this takes longer than just running the extra query.  You might want to familiarize yourself with the other "*ect" methods in Ruby such as select and reject.  Here's a decent article reviewing them:

https://blog.abushady.com/2014/08/27/select-reject-collect-detect-inject.html

Comment: Overall, do you mean using `sum` is the fastest option for this performance-wise?

Comment: yes, in my experience sum is going to run faster than letting ruby iterate through all of the objects unless the total number of products is quite small.  I would recommend keeping that kind of calculation in the database to make your app more scalable.